# HC-SR04 distance = 0 using pigpio in C++

Tags: sensor, c++, pigpio

As the title says, the distance in my sonar is giving me 0, I think I found out the problem, but the code was working fine with wiringPi.

Functions:

- I only changed names to be equal to Arduino
- digitalRead = gpioRead
- digitalWrite = gpioWrite
- delayMicroseconds = gpioDelay
- micros = gpioTick

This function is in a class, so I'm copying what matters.

```
float distance()
    {
        static float old = 0.0;
        float duration = 0.0, distance = 0.0, threshold = 0.01;

        digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(2);

        digitalWrite(TrigPin, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(10);
        digitalWrite(TrigPin, LOW);

        duration = pulseIn(EchoPin, HIGH);
        distance = (duration / 2.0) * 0.0343 / 100.0;

        if (old == 0.0 || (abs(distance - old) <= threshold))
            return old = distance;
        else
            return old;
    }
```

Here is where I think the problem is:

```
uint32_t pulseIn(uint8_t pin, uint8_t state, uint32_t timeout = 1000000L);

uint32_t pulseIn(uint8_t pin, uint8_t state, uint32_t timeout)
{
  uint32_t start = micros();
  while (digitalRead(pin) == state && (micros() - start) < timeout);
  while (digitalRead(pin) != state && (micros() - start) < timeout);
  start = micros();
  while (digitalRead(pin) == state && (micros() - start) < timeout);
  return micros() - start;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pigpio sonar ranger example html is not displaying for reasons I don't understand.

However this is the code given in the example.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pigpio.h>

/*

P1  Name  gpio    used for

 2  5V    ---     5V
 6  GND   ---     Ground
24  CE0   8       Sonar echo
26  CE1   7       Sonar trigger

*/

#define SONAR_TRIGGER 7
#define SONAR_ECHO    8

/* forward prototypes */

void sonarTrigger(void);

void sonarEcho(int gpio, int level, uint32_t tick);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (gpioInitialise()<0) return 1;

   gpioSetMode(SONAR_TRIGGER, PI_OUTPUT);
   gpioWrite  (SONAR_TRIGGER, PI_OFF);

   gpioSetMode(SONAR_ECHO,    PI_INPUT);

   /* update sonar 20 times a second, timer #0 */

   gpioSetTimerFunc(0, 50, sonarTrigger); /* every 50ms */

   /* monitor sonar echos */

   gpioSetAlertFunc(SONAR_ECHO, sonarEcho);

   while (1) sleep(1);

   gpioTerminate();

   return 0;
}

void sonarTrigger(void)
{
   /* trigger a sonar reading */

   gpioWrite(SONAR_TRIGGER, PI_ON);

   gpioDelay(10); /* 10us trigger pulse */

   gpioWrite(SONAR_TRIGGER, PI_OFF);
}

void sonarEcho(int gpio, int level, uint32_t tick)
{
   static uint32_t startTick, firstTick=0;

   int diffTick;

   if (!firstTick) firstTick = tick;

   if (level == PI_ON)
   {
      startTick = tick;
   }
   else if (level == PI_OFF)
   {
      diffTick = tick - startTick;

      printf("%u %u\n", tick-firstTick, diffTick);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your code and the code I posted in the question works fine. The problem was, that I was testing the PWM with an LED and I had the Vcc connected to the LED pin and when I changed the circuit I forgot to change the Vcc to 5V, meaning the sensor was using 3.3V and because of it was returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are a working solution for the WiringPi library [here](https://github.com/omaraflak/HC-SR04-Raspberry-Pi-C-).

In my opinion WiringPi was much easier. Sadly it is not supported anymore. But we can change a few things if we want to use pigpio:

```
pinmode(pin, OUTPUT);
pinmode(pin, INPUT);
digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
digitalRead(pin);
```

would become

```
gpioSetMode(pin, PI_OUTPUT);
gpioSetMode(pin, PI_INPUT);
gpioWrite(pin, PI_OFF);
gpioWrite(pin, PI_ON);
gpioRead(pin);
```

Important information from the documentation:

The level of a GPIO. Low or High.

```
PI_OFF 0
PI_ON 1

PI_CLEAR 0
PI_SET 1

PI_LOW 0
PI_HIGH 1
```

So as example `PI_OFF`, `PI_CLEAR`, `PI_LOW` or `0` are the same and `PI_ON`, `PI_SET`, `PI_HIGH` or `1` are also the same.

I have not tested the following, as I do not have an HC-SR04 at hand at the moment. The code from the question has an error with `HIGH` and `LOW` in my opinion, because this should be renamed to `PI_HIGH` and `PI_LOW` respectively. So it would be conceivable that the following could work:

```
float distance()
{
    static float old = 0.0;
    float duration = 0.0, distance = 0.0, threshold = 0.01;

    digitalWrite(TrigPin, PI_LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    digitalWrite(TrigPin, PI_HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(TrigPin, PI_LOW);

    duration = pulseIn(EchoPin, PI_HIGH);
    distance = (duration / 2.0) * 0.0343 / 100.0;

    if (old == 0.0 || (abs(distance - old) <= threshold))
        return old = distance;
    else
        return old;
}
```

Now I have pointed to a WiringPi solution. This I will now also present. I get new Raspberry Pi accessories at the end of the week, there is then also a HC-SR04, then I can verify my solution. The change looks like this:

**libSonar.h**

```
#ifndef DEF_SONAR
#define DEF_SONAR

class Sonar
{
  public:
    Sonar();
    void init(int trigger, int echo);
    double distance(int timeout);

  private:
    void recordPulseLength();
    int trigger;
    int echo;
    volatile long startTimeUsec;
    volatile long endTimeUsec;
    double distanceMeters;
    long travelTimeUsec;
    long now;
};

#endif
```

**libSonar.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include "libSonar.h"

Sonar::Sonar(){}

void Sonar::init(int trigger, int echo)
{
    this->trigger=trigger;
    this->echo=echo;
    gpioSetMode(trigger, PI_OUTPUT);
    gpioSetMode(echo, PI_INPUT);

    gpioWrite(trigger, PI_LOW);
    delay(500);
}

double Sonar::distance(int timeout)
{
    delay(10);

    gpioWrite(trigger, PI_HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    gpioWrite(trigger, PI_LOW);

    now=micros();

    while (digitalRead(echo) == PI_LOW && micros()-now<timeout);
        recordPulseLength();

    travelTimeUsec = endTimeUsec - startTimeUsec;
    distanceMeters = 100*((travelTimeUsec/1000000.0)*340.29)/2;

    return distanceMeters;
}

void Sonar::recordPulseLength()
{
    startTimeUsec = micros();
    while ( digitalRead(echo) == PI_HIGH );
    endTimeUsec = micros();
}
```

**libSonarSample.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include "libSonar.h"

using namespace std;

int trigger = 1;
int echo = 0;

int main()
{
    if (gpioInitialise() == -1)
        return -1;

    Sonar sonar;
    sonar.init(trigger, echo);

    while(1){
        cout << "Distance is " << sonar.distance(30000) << " cm." << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm curious about that myself now. Accordingly I could translate some code from WiringPi to pgpio. Seems to be very easy.